# Ответ от сайта приходит в нечитабельном виде

Tags: java, okhttp

Подскажите, что делаю не правильно.
Отправляю запрос на сайт и вывожу ответ. Иногда ответ выводится в читабельном виде, а иногда нет. Такой же запрос но через php возвращает ответ в читабельном виде.
Вот мой код (Java, lib okhttp3)

```
    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    JavaNetCookieJar javaNetCookieJar = new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager);
    cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().cookieJar(javaNetCookieJar).build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(siteURL)
            .method("GET", null)
            .addHeader("Host", hostName)
            .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
            .addHeader("User-Agent", userAgent)
            .addHeader("X-IG-Connection-Speed", "-1kbps")
            .addHeader("X-IG-Connection-Type", "WIFI")
            .addHeader("X-IG-Bandwidth-Speed-KBPS", "-1.000")
            .addHeader("X-IG-Bandwidth-TotalBytes-B", "0")
            .addHeader("X-IG-Bandwidth-TotalTime-MS", "0")
            .addHeader("Accept-Language", language)
            .addHeader("X-Bloks-Is-Layout-RTL", "false")
            .addHeader("X-Bloks-Version-Id", XBloksVersionId)
            .addHeader("X-FB-HTTP-Engine", "Liger")
            .addHeader("X-IG-Android-ID", device_id)
            .addHeader("X-IG-App-Locale", locale)
            .addHeader("X-IG-Device-Locale", locale)
            .addHeader("X-IG-Mapped-Locale", locale)
            .addHeader("X-Pigeon-Rawclienttime", DataReader.getUNIXTime())
            .addHeader("X-Pigeon-Session-Id", XPigeonSessionId)
            .addHeader("Connection", "close")
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

Comment: Хм. При удалении параметра .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate") ответ возвращается в нормальном виде. Но как тогда он работает? Почему иногда алгоритм сжатия нормально расшифровывает ответ, а иногда нет?

Comment: Посылая заголовок `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` вы говорите сайту, что можете и в gzip, и в deflate. А тот уже на свое усмотрение выбирает алгоритм сжатия. И почему сервер то одним, то другим делает не знаю, мб это зависит от рандома

Answer (score 0):

Вернул параметр, только вместо значений "gzip, defalte" убрал gzip и все приходит в нормальной кодировки.